# PrependTo item only ONCE in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following DOM-tree relationship

```
<div class="div-class"></div>
<table class="table-class"></table>

<div class="div-class"></div>
<table class="table-class"></table>
```

What I would like to do is move the `.table-class` inside the `.div-class`, but when I run jQuery with `prependTo('.div-class')` I get the following output:

```
<div class="div-class">
  <table class="table-class"></table> <!-- they get added TWICE -->
  <table class="table-class"></table> <!-- they get added TWICE -->
</div>

<div class="div-class">
  <table class="table-class"></table> <!-- they get added TWICE -->
  <table class="table-class"></table> <!-- they get added TWICE -->
</div>
```

I just need to move the first/immediate occurrence of `.table-class` inside that `div.class`. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're prepending *all* the `.div-class` elements to all the `.table-class` elements at once.

To solve this you can use `prepend()` on the `.div-class` elements, passing the method a function which returns the element to prepend to. Try this:

```js
$('.div-class').prepend(function() {
  return $(this).next('table');
});
```

```css
div { 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #C00; 
}
table { 
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0C0; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class"></div>
<table class="table-class"></table>

<div class="div-class"></div>
<table class="table-class"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are prepending the table to all *.div-class* element.  You can iterate are relatively prepend element.

```js
$('.table-class').each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).prev('.div-class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">First Div</div>
<table class="table-class">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="div-class">Second Div</div>
<table class="table-class">
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`next()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb5rTypYPVAhXMsI8KHe4vC74QFggzMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fnext%2F&usg=AFQjCNE498BhQOD1vTQGmOyAhS4eKba-Pw)

```js
$('.div-class').each(function(){
  $(this).prepend(function() {
    return $(this).next('.table-class')
  })
})
console.log($('body')[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
</div>

<table class="table-class" id="one">
</table>


<div class="div-class">
</div>

<table class="table-class" id="two">
</table>
```

Comment: If you're using the `prepend(fn)` signature then you don't need to use `each()`. See my answer for more info