# Jquery: prependTo item inside child item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue similar to this one:

[PrependTo item only ONCE in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051812/prependto-item-only-once-in-jquery/)

But my DOM structure is:

```
<div class="div-class">
    <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
<table class="table-class"></table>
```

And the desired output I would like using jQuery is:

```
<div class="div-class">
    <div class="child-div">
        <table class="table-class"></table>
    </div><!--child-class-->
</div><!--div-class-->
```

But the code on that solution doesn't work, and I have tried to do it inside the loop, but to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either append it to the child div or create a string and then pass that into the html() of the div as I have done below. The benefit of building the element as a string and then passing it in - is that you are affecting the DOM only once - this is important if you are appending a lot of tr's or td's within each tr.

If you are doing this as part of a lop - then you can use the index of that loop to control the display or do it outside the loop and use the loop to add the tr's to the str before updating the DOM at the end.

Note I added a tr with a single td to demonstrate the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var str = '';

str += '<table class="table-class">';
  str += '<tr>';
    str += '<td>test</td>';
  str += '</tr>';
 str += '</table>';

$('.child-div').html(str)
})
```

```css
table{border: solid 1px #333}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
    <div class="child-div">
    </div><!--child-class-->
</div><!--div-class-->
```

Comment: I need this multiple times, I believe your string concatenation only runs once?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one working example. In this example I have used `child-div` parent and its next element to prepernt to `child-div`.

```js
$('.div-class .child-div').prepend(function() {
  return $(this).parent().next('table');
});
```

```css
div { 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #C00; 
}
table { 
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0C0; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-class">
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
<table class="table-class"></table>

<div class="div-class">
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
<table class="table-class"></table>
```